# Is there any way to get the date time on the "you replied to this message on [xxx]"?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to do a email export from outlook to excel macro which includes the recipient, email subject and most importantly the date time of email reply. I have tried searching for the list of mail item properties.

Besides `.LastModificationTime`, I cant seem to find any property closer to the exact date time on the **"you replied to this message on [xxx]"**

Answer (score 0):

You need `PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME` (DASL name is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10820040`) MAPI property, it can be accessed using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`.
Take a look at the message with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click IMessage button to see the available properties.