# Get the date of reply

Tags: vba, outlook

The answer to [Is there any way to get the date time on the “you replied to this message on [xxx]”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578476/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-date-time-on-the-you-replied-to-this-message-on-xx) describes a solution with the property PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME.

If that property is absent in the list of properties, can I find the date or the message-answer another way?

There is only property PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED in the window "get prop" of the program "outlookSpy".

```
Sub Extracting()
Dim myolApp As Outlook.Application
Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myFolder, ssBox As Outlook.Folder
Dim sch As Outlook.Search
Dim rsts As Outlook.Results
Dim sDate, eDate, strS, strF, DatiRe As String
Dim i As Integer

Set myolApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set myNamespace = myolApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set mySheet = xlApp.Worksheets("Ëèñò1")
sDate = Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy")
eDate = Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy")
i = 1
While i <= myNamespace.Folders.Count
 If myNamespace.Folders.Item(i).Name = "mmm@mail.ru" Then
   Set myFolder = myNamespace.GetFolderFromID(myNamespace.Folders.Item(i).EntryID, myNamespace.Folders.Item(i).StoreID)
   i = myNamespace.Folders.Count
 End If
 i = i + 1
Wend

blnSearchComp = False
Set ssBox = myFolder.Folders("Inbox")
strS = "'" & ssBox.FolderPath & "'"
strF = "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived >= '" & sDate & " 0:00' AND urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived <= '" & eDate & " 23:59'"
Set sch = myolApp.AdvancedSearch(strS, strF, False, "aaa")
While blnSearchComp = False
    DoEvents
Wend
Set ssBox = myFolder.Folders("Outbox")
Set rsts = sch.Results
For i = 1 To rsts.Count
    Debug.Print rsts.Item(i).SenderName
    DatiRe = GetDaTiAnswer(rsts.Item(i).ConversationIndex, rsts.Item(i).ConversationTopic, ssBox.FolderPath)
    Set NextRow = mySheet.Range("A" & mySheet.Rows.Count).End(-4162).Offset(1)
    NextRow.Resize(, 4).Value = Array(rsts.Item(i).SenderEmailAddress, rsts.Item(i).ReceivedTime, DatiRe, rsts.Item(i).Subject)
Next
End Sub

Function GetDaTiAnswer(ByVal iConvIndex, iConvTopic, parP As String) As String
 Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
 Dim oSch As Outlook.Search
 Dim oRes As Outlook.Results
 Dim parC As String
 Dim j As Integer
 blnSearchComp = False
 Set oApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
 parC = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0070001F = '" & iConvTopic & "'"
 Set oSch = oApp.AdvancedSearch("'" & parP & "'", parC, False, "aaa")
 While blnSearchComp = False
    DoEvents
 Wend
 Set oRes = oSch.Results
 For j = 1 To oRes.Count
    Debug.Print oRes.Item(j).SenderName
    If Left(oRes.Item(j).ConversationIndex, Len(oRes.Item(j).ConversationIndex) - 10) = iConvIndex Then
      GetDaTiAnswer = oRes.Item(j).SentOn
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Comment: You could look in the sent items folder?

Comment: i see that item in the sent folder, but how can i work out it's the very thing

Comment: If you replied through the Outlook UI, PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME and PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED will always be set. Do you have a scenario when this is not the case?

Comment: I reply from Outlook by the click of the button "Reply", but PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME is absent in the list of properties. Account - imap/smtp

Comment: I guess I'll take your advice from this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922081/developing-outlook-add-in-to-check-if-the-sent-mail-item-has-been-replied-to

Comment: if an account take place to POP3 or Exchange server this property (PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME) is present, for IMAP it's absent

Comment: Thank you, Dmitry, for your advices from the other topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa172005(v=office.11).aspx you should be able to access the `PR_CLIENT_SUBMIT_TIME` which is the `MailItem.SentOn` property.

So if you find the item in the sent items, that's the property to look for.

Comment: i don't know how can i do it knowing properties only the mailitem from the inbox

Comment: i don't realize how can i get the "DaTiRe" (date/time reply) from the code above

Comment: thank you, Floris, for your participation, i worked out this problem, finding property SentOn from Outbox with conversationIndex